How can i find eigen's system path in conda's setup?
I need to provide it as the "cmake prefix path". The build fails if i don't provide the correct path. I can't edit the cmake file directly in this case due to restrictions. I need to do it all inside a docker container prepared by someone else through the bash terminal.

I used "conda list eigen". I navigated to the directory address that it gave me as the result. I checked the "include" directory over there. I found the "eigen" directory in there. I used the full path for it. Since i couldn't find a solution for this issue online, therefore i decided to share what i found over here just in case someone else needs it.
